# how to remove the lastchild element of dynamically generated DIV and return the html as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How to remove the lastchild of the dynamically generated div and regenerate the html as string.
Sample HTML DIV

```
strHtmlString = "<div contenteditable='true' id='undefined'>Test1</div>
    <div contenteditable='true' id='sentenceFreeTextField67' type='sentenceFreeTextField'>One</div>
    <div id='multiselectAnchors' type='multi'>
        <div id='options32' >Two</div>
        <div contenteditable='true' id='sentenceFreeTextField68' type='sentenceFreeTextField'>One</div>
    </div>
    <div id='blank4' contenteditable='true' type='blankField'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div id='Div1' type='multi'>
        <div id='options33' >Three</div>
        <div contenteditable='true' id='sentenceFreeTextField69' type='sentenceFreeTextField'>One</div>
    </div>"
```

here is the code sample

```
if (($('<DIV/>').html(strSentence)[0].lastChild.lastChild.type === 'sentenceFreeTextField') && (!$.trim($('<DIV/>').html(strSentence)[0].lastChild.lastChild.innerText))) {

strHtmlString = $('<DIV/>').html(strSentence)[0].lastChild.lastChild.remove().html; (this remove().html doesn't work) 

}
```

the need is to delete the lastchild of the div at runtime and convert back to string as it was earlier. I can do string manipulation however, might not the be the right way, please suggest

Comment: which one is the last child div?

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = $(strHtmlString);
// dont know what you meant by last child, so taking the id
el.children().find("#sentenceFreeTextField69").remove();

var str = el.wrap("<div/>").parent().html()
```

Comment: If lastchild in the div is of type 'sentenceFreeTextField' and its value is blank then remove this lastchild and regenerate the entire html removing the sentenceFreeTextField69 div

resulthtmlstring = oldhtmlstring - <div contenteditable='true' id='sentenceFreeTextField69' type='sentenceFreeTextField'>One</div>

Answer (score 1):

Generate a DIV dynamically:

```
$('body').append('<div>');
```

Access the DIV immediately after generation:

```
var $divElement = $('body').append('<div>').find('div');
```

Get the last child:

```
var $lastChildElement = $divElement.last();
```

Get the HTML of the last child (more specifically, the `innerHTML`):

```
var $lastChildHTML = $lastChildElement.html();
```

Do it all together then you turn around:

```
var $lastChildHTML = $('body').append('<div>').find('div').last().html();
```

That's what it's all about.

Answer (score 1):

```
var last = $(element).children(':last-child');
var html = $(last).html();
$(last).remove();
var newHtml = $(element).html();
//incase you want the html with it's parent as well do this
var newHtml = $(element).parent().html();
```

Comment: `$(element).html();` is innerHTML, does not include the element itself

Comment: @MoazzamKhan the OP requested the HTML as a string

Comment: @Ozzy I meant, the innerHTML does not have the element itself as string.

Comment: @MoazzamKhan That would matter (and then you would need the outerHTML) except the OP hasn't made it clear which element he wants to return the HTML for.

Comment: @Ozzy - he said - ` convert back to string as it was earlier`